# How to create two windows separately using MFC?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

Now I have developed an application that illustrates two windows on main frame of MFC. I have developed with SDI in MFC, but did not use MDI as I need to hide menu bar. When the program starts I have only one window. How can I add one more window by code? and how can I update each screen with different data?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from hiding the menu bar in an MDI application.

Comment: @CodyGray What do you mean? How can I add new window only use code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 views inside a single window. The 2 views may be separated using [CSplitterWnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xttbe5t.aspx). You can have a look here about what [different kinds of views you can have](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezc3635w.aspx).

**Updated:**

As per your comment below, since you want separate windows with different data, you must use MDI. This is what it is designed for.

Comment: Thank in advanced. But I need two separated windows, it does not mean dividing a window into two parts. I knew CSplitterWnd.

Comment: Do you want the multiple windows to be within the mainframe window (that is classical MDI)? Or do you want multiple mainframe windows (search for "Multiple Top Level Windows" at codeproject.com)?

Comment: Can you show me the way to create two windows in MDI by using code because I had removed menu bar.

Comment: Use the MFC wizard to create MDI app. You would define 2 different sets of document/childframe/view in your app. In CWinApp create those document templates and in CMainFrm create a document of each type with the required data.

Comment: I mean two windows on the same main frame. I scare that your way display two separated windows.

Comment: My method will show 2 child windows inside same main frame. You can see the picture here: http://silviuardelean.ro/2010/07/23/versionable-object%E2%80%99s-serialization-in-mdi-applications/

Comment: I have tried following your instruction, but maybe I implement wrong. When I run in debug mode it display a small dialog to choose one of two ?. How can I fix it?